# Django url regex with non-capturing parentheses breaks app

Tags: python, regex, django, url

Good day SO!

I'm working on a little change on how URLs are displayed. Currently an url reverse takes a PK of an object. I want to keep it that way, and just show
a slug of an object in the URL for readability. 
So concrete said, I want a dummy slug in my URL.

For this I used a non-capturing parentheses in my URL regex:

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)(?:/(?P<slug>[\w\d-]+))/$', views.Detail.as_view(), name='detail'),
```

Now I can visit

> localhost:8000/blogs/12/title-of-my-blog/
>   or
>   localhost:8000/blogs/12/

Both will display the blog without errors, but now the trouble starts. 
If I press the publish button, it won't publish as expected:

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/publish/$', views.Publish.as_view(), name='publish'),

class Publish(PermissionRequiredMixin, View):
    """ Publish the current blog """
    permission_required = 'blogs.publish_blog'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print('get')
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk', None)
        blogs.services.blog.publish(pk)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/blogs/' + pk)
```

(this also counts for other the buttons like Edit/Share/etc)

Now, if i take away the non-capturing parentheses group ((?:/(?P[\w\d-]+))?/$) it all works properly again.

I've been reading about the non-capturing parentheses, the url reversing
possibilities and restrictions, but I can't find out why it messes up the
system without any errors.

Can you, if you understand what is going wrong, please give me an explanation
of why it is going wrong and give me a push in the right direction to solve
this problem?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: "It won't publish as expected" - what does that mean? What happens? What errors do you see?

Comment: Actually, it does nothing.. in the terminal it shows [17/Dec/2015 19:28:05] "GET /blogs/18/publish/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1378 - But it stays on the current page with no changes at all... No errors to work with unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You presumably have your detail URL listed before the publish one in your urls.py. That means that /blogs/18/publish will be captured by the publish URL, since "publish" is a valid value for the slug field. So that URL will always be served by the detail view.

You could swap the order of the URLs to fix this.

Note by the way that the "publish" action, since it modifies data, should be a POST, not a GET.